# C# NullPointerException on arr.Max(x => x.Length)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

It's not the first time I'm getting this error on snippets I found on forums and I cannot understand why. Also I'm yet a `C#` noob.

Whenever I try something like `arr.Max(x => x.Length)` I'm getting a NPE on `x` in `x.Length`. Something must be wrong with the param variable I'm passing, because I only get this error on execution.

```
private string[,] jaggedTo2D(string[][] arr)
{
    string[,] arr2 = new string[arr.Length, arr.Max(x => x.Length)];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].Length; j++)
        {
            arr2[i, j] = arr[i][j];
        }
    }

    return arr2;
}
```

Comment: Is any of `arr` elements null?

Comment: The snippets usually does not include error checking. Apparently the variable `arr` is not `null`, but some element is (jagged array is array of arrays).

Comment: This question should not be considerated a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it. While it is about a null reference exception this one is specifically about a null reference exception inside a Linq function, which has some considerations of it's own.

Comment: The real answer to your question is that you're passing in an array of arrays (a jagged array), where at least one of the members (in the first rank of the array) hasn't been initialised with a new array inside it.

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

```
    private string[,] jaggedTo2D(string[][] arr) {
        string[,] arr2 = new string[arr.Length, arr.Max(x => null != x ? x.Length : 0)];
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].Length; j++) {
                arr2[i, j] = arr[i][j];
            }
        }

        return arr2;
    }
```

I've added check for the `null` element.